# IllegalArgumentException: column _id doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, illegalargumentexception

I have been trying to display records from a database in ListView. i am able to add records as confirmed using adb shell commands. i can view the records there. but when i tried to implement a view button to display records it just crashes with the error : illegalArgumentException. column_id not existing is the root of it. but i am sure it exists! please help as this is driving me absolutely mad!

**DISPLAYCURSOR** code:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_cursor);
   filldata();

   }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void filldata(){
    db.open();

   Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecords();
  startManagingCursor(cursor);

   String[] columns = new String[] {DBAdapter.invest_type,DBAdapter.curr_per_share_price, DBAdapter.share_name,
   DBAdapter.no_of_shares,DBAdapter.share_identity,DBAdapter.purchase_price,
   DBAdapter.purchase_from,DBAdapter.purchase_date,DBAdapter.purchase_contact};

  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.investmenttype,R.id.currpershareprice,R.id.sharename,R.id.shareno,R.id.shareid,                

   R.id.purprice,
   R.id.purfrom,R.id.purdate,R.id.purcon};
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( this, R.layout.row, cursor, columns, to);
   this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
   db.close();
  }   
     }
```

**DBAdapter** `getallrecords` function:

```
  public Cursor getAllRecords()
   {
    return db.query(DATABASETABLE, new String[] { _id,invest_type,curr_per_share_price,
   share_name ,no_of_shares,share_identity,purchase_price,purchase_from,purchase_date,purchase_contact}, null,           
   null, null,null, null);        }
```

**ROW.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/investmenttype"
android:layout_width="140dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/currpershareprice"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/investmenttype"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/investmenttype"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/investmenttype" />

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/sharename"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/currpershareprice"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/currpershareprice"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/currpershareprice" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/shareno"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sharename"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sharename"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sharename" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/shareid"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/shareno"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shareno"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shareno" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/purprice"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/shareid"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/shareid"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shareid" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/purfrom"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/purprice"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/purprice"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/purprice" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/purdate"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/purfrom"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/purfrom"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/purfrom" />
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/purcon"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/purdate"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/purdate"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/purdate" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**activity_display_cursor**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/nodata"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

entire **DBAdapter** code:

```
package com.example.studentdatabase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
public class DBAdapter{
    public static final String DATABASENAME = "new";
    public static final String DATABASETABLE="equities";
    public static final String _id="id";
    public static  final String invest_type = "investmenttype";
    public static final String curr_per_share_price = "currentshareprice";
    public static final String share_name="sharename";
    public static final String no_of_shares="noofshares";
    public static final String share_identity="shareidentity";
    public static final String purchase_price="purchaseprice";
    public static final String purchase_from="webagent";
    public static final String purchase_date="purchasedate";
    public static final String purchase_contact="agentcontactno";
    public static final String DATABASECREATE=
    "create table if not exists equities(" +
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
    "investmenttype VARCHAR not null," +
    "currentshareprice INTEGER," +
    "sharename VARCHAR not null," +
    "noofshares INTEGER,"+
    "shareidentity VARCHAR not null,"+
    "purchaseprice INTEGER," +
    "webagent VARCHAR not null," +
    "purchasedate DATE,"+
    "agentcontactno INTEGER);";
    public static final int DATABASEVERSION= 38;
    public static final String  TAG="DBAdapter";
    private final Context context;
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context,DATABASENAME,null,DATABASEVERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            //  try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASECREATE);
                //
            }
            /* catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS equities");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
    public long addRecord(String investmenttype,String currentshareprice,String noofshares,String
    sharename,String shareidentity,String purchaseprice,
    String purchasedate,String webagent,String agentcontactno)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(invest_type, investmenttype);
        initialValues.put(curr_per_share_price,currentshareprice);
        initialValues.put(share_name, sharename);
        initialValues.put(no_of_shares, noofshares);
        initialValues.put(share_identity,shareidentity);
        initialValues.put(purchase_price, purchaseprice);
        initialValues.put(purchase_from, webagent);
        initialValues.put(purchase_date, purchasedate);
        initialValues.put(purchase_contact,agentcontactno);
        return db.insert(DATABASETABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
    //---retrieves a particular record---
    public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
        db.query(true, DATABASETABLE, new String[] {
            _id,
            invest_type, curr_per_share_price, share_name,no_of_shares,share_identity,purchase_price,
            purchase_from,purchase_date,purchase_contact
        }
        ,
        _id + "=" + rowId, null, null, null,null,null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
    public Cursor getAllRecords()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASETABLE, new String[] {
            "_id","invest_type","curr_per_share_price",
            "share_name","no_of_shares","share_identity","purchase_price","purchase_from","purchase_date","purchase_contact"
        }
        ,
        null, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

> 06-10 12:38:17.965: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(649): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: _id,
>   db=/data/data/com.example.studentdatabase/databases/new
>        06-10 12:38:17.965: D/AndroidRuntime(649): Shutting down VM
>        06-10 12:38:17.965: W/dalvikvm(649): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity C 
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.studentdatabase/com.example.studentdatabase.DisplayCursor}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while
>   compiling: SELECT _id, invest_type,  curr_per_share_price, share_name,
>   no_of_shares, share_identity, purchase_price, purchase_from,
>   purchase_date,  purchase_contact FROM equities
>        06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)   06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)   06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)    06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    06-10 12:38:18.045:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(649): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such c  column: _id: ,
>   while compiling: SELECT _id, invest_type, curr_per_share_price,
>   share_name, no_of_shares,  share_identity, purchase_price,
>   purchase_from, purchase_date, purchase_contact FROM equities   06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native
>   Method)   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.
>   (SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)   06-10 12:38:18.045:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
>        06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   com.example.studentdatabase.DBAdapter.getAllRecords(DBAdapter.java:127)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   com.example.studentdatabase.DisplayCursor.filldata(DisplayCursor.java:34)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at com.example.studentdatabase.DisplayCursor.onCreate(DisplayCursor.java:27)
>       06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)    06-10
>   12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
>   06-10 12:38:18.045: E/AndroidRuntime(649):   ... 11 more

Comment: i have posted the layouts and display_cursor activity along with DBAdapter code for getAllrecords() PLEASE HELP

Comment: Can you post how you create the db please?

Comment: Are `_id`, `invest_type`, `curr_per_share_price` and others all string? Or they are column names?

Comment: Sam Rad they are all column names

Comment: UPDATE: posted DBAdapter code. Please help.

Comment: Hi sam, i have a new question(same project though) . see if you can tell what's wrong. or direct me in the right path atleast.thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132559/java-lang-nullpointerexception-displaying-records-from-database-in-an-expandab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html):

> Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The
>   Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Other than this, I think this line:

```
return db.query(DATABASETABLE, new String[] { 
                                   _id, invest_type, curr_per_share_price,
                                   share_name, no_of_shares, share_identity,
                                   purchase_price, purchase_from, purchase_date,
                                   purchase_contact 
               }, null, null, null,null, null);
```

Should be this way if they are all column names:

```
return db.query(DATABASETABLE, new String[] { 
                                   "_id", "invest_type", "curr_per_share_price",
                                   "share_name", "no_of_shares", 
                                   "share_identity", "purchase_price", 
                                   "purchase_from", "purchase_date", 
                                   "purchase_contact" 
               }, null, null, null,null, null);
```

Comment: i tried changing the columns as you said. didn't work. and cursor already includes the column "_id". i even tried upgrading. this is driving me nuts.could there be something wrong with my row or  activity_display_cursor layouts?

Comment: @user2468835, the error you're getting has nothing to do with layout. `IllegalArgumentException` normally means that you are calling a method without proper arguments. Check your `Logcat` and see which line exactly gives you this error. Then report back to me. I suggest to edit your question and include Logcat as well.

Comment: @user2468835, I'm in the middle of something now. I'll keep you informed within few minutes.

Comment: @user2468835, do one thing. Uninstall your application and update the `DATABASECREATE` string to `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` instead of `id`. Test again. If it still doesn't work send me your full application and I will try it on my system. If possible.

Comment: umm, sorry for the stupid question. but by uninstall do you mean delete after keeping backup?

Comment: What backup? Do you have data in your SQLite table? I mean uninstall the APK from emulator or the device you are testing with.

Comment: yeah, i do have data. the add record thing works for sure. could view the records and table using adb shell. but just sample data, so ohkay, will uninstall and see.

Comment: @user2468835, I tried something. After you uninstalled the APK change `public static final String _id="id";` to `public static final String _id="_id";` and also `"create table if not exists equities(" +                     "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + ...` to `"create table if not exists equities(" +                     "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + ...`

Comment: @user2468835, have you removed the `""` from `string[]`? Disregard my answer's update. Leave them as they were. Like this: `new String[] {                                    _id, invest_type, curr_per_share_price`.

Comment: it's on 4.2.2 though. hope it's not a problem

Comment: @user2468835, what's the problem? It works find on my emulator. I added a record and then I viewed it. No error so far. Where do you get the error?

Comment: what?? how is it working for you? i don't understand. i get the error when i click view button .

Comment: @user2468835, That's probably because you Altered the Table schema. Have you uninstalled the APK?

Comment: DAMNN. turns out i didn't uninstall properly. sorry for such an obvious question and wasting your time. what can i do for you? i can't vote your answer up, don't have enough points :( THANKS ALOT!

Comment: done. just realised such a button was there. first time i posted a question you see :)

Comment: @user2468835, Good Luck and ask more ;)