# java.lang.NullPointerException : displaying records from database in an expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, button, nullpointerexception, expandable

As the question dictates, i need to display records from database, different record for each child.ie,
child 1= record 1 data. child 2 =record 2 data.so and so.
i came up with the following code for display:

```
package com.example.moolah;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DisplayActivity extends ListActivity {
DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_cursor); 

    Button viewbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 //    viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new Buttonx());


}

public class Buttonx extends DisplayActivity implements Button.OnClickListener{
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    { 


Button viewbutton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Object viewid=viewbutton.getTag();
            int i=Integer.parseInt(viewid.toString());          
MyCustomAdapter c=new MyCustomAdapter();
            long id=c.getChildId(0,i);
        //DisplayCursor d;
            //d.filldata();                
         db.open();
           // View view;
           Cursor cursor = db.getRecord(id);
           startManagingCursor(cursor);

            String[] columns = new String[] {DBAdapter.invest_type,DBAdapter.curr_per_share_price, DBAdapter.share_name,
                    DBAdapter.no_of_shares,DBAdapter.share_identity,DBAdapter.purchase_price,
                    DBAdapter.purchase_from,DBAdapter.purchase_date,DBAdapter.purchase_contact};

            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.investmenttype,R.id.currpershareprice,R.id.sharename,R.id.shareno,R.id.shareid, R.id.purprice,
                    R.id.purfrom,R.id.purdate,R.id.purcon};
            SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( this, R.layout.row, cursor, columns, to);
            this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);


           db.close();
    } 
}
```

This displays "no data" in text, although my database has data, as confirmed using command prompt adb shell.
So i assume it doesn't have access to the onClick method.
Now if i uncomment the line commented in onCreate method,it gets access, but results in a NullPointerException at
              viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new Buttonx());//onCreate method

How do i get access to onClick without generating this exception and display the records as desired? 
i think i am going fundamentally wrong somewhere. if someone could point out the flaw i would be greatful.you see, this thing is driving me nuts.:/

LOGCAT:

```
     06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.example.moolah/com.example.moolah.DisplayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)        
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at com.example.moolah.DisplayActivity.onCreate(DisplayActivity.java:21)
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at             android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
    06-17 17:33:32.444: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Move this inside onCreate

   DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);

Comment: post your stack trace for further assistance

Comment: i shall try that out now.also stack trace shows cause of error as viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new Buttonx());

Comment: and it's access to onClick that is required. already have access to onCreate. i get "no data" displayed. but when i uncomment the setOnClickListener line in onCreate, it generates nullpointer except.

Comment: you are doing it wrong

Comment: try the below but it would help if you post the stack trace

Comment: UPDATE i posted stack trace

Comment: whats on line 21 DisplayActivity.java

Comment: theSetOnClickListener method is linked to the button. so could there be  a problem with reading the button resource id button2? it doesn't say that's the problem . but could that be it>?

Comment: do you have a button with id button 2 in your xml layout activity_display_cursor

Comment: you have to extend activity i guess instead of listactivity

Comment: no i don't . that button2 is a view button from my child.xml

Comment: activity_display_cursor.xml contains only a text view and list view.

Comment: thats why you are getting  `NPE`. define button in  `activity_display_cursor.xml` and then try

Comment: but then the view button from the child should link to the onClick . How else do i do it?

Comment: extend a activity. define a button in your xml and a listview on top of the button. initialize your listview and button . on button click set your adapter to listview

Comment: oh. i don't really understand that. could you elaborate? extend activity in DisplayACtivity you mean? and i have a button and text view in my child view. should i change that to list view instead of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like below. Also post the stack trace so that we can help you further

```
public class DisplayActivity extends ListActivity {
DBAdapter db;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_cursor); 
 db=new DBAdapter(this);  
Button viewbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
viewbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
       @override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
             // do something
       }   

});
}
```

Edit:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <ListView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/lv" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // set your adapter to listview here
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No raghunandan. the above is one way to do it . i agree. that is how i was doing it initially.and i tried it again even. but it showed nullexception at setOnClickListener. wait i'll post stack trace for you.

Comment: @user2468835 it's a null pointer exception. whats on line 21. some thing in line 21 is null

Comment: yup.line 21 is the view.setOnClickListener. that's what generates the exception. some trouble with reading i think.

Comment: yes. i did. it generated the same exception at setOnClickListener too

Comment: hey. sorry for the q, but in the onClick if i set adapter to listview, won't it give error because i extend activity and not listactivity?

Comment: try it and inform coz you have initialized listview and you only set the adapter to listview

Comment: great. this really seems like the right way to do it. i tried it. now it says my constructor simplecursoradapter is undefined and method setlistadapter undefined for view.onclicklistener.

Comment: i think your method is right. but i'm missing something somewhere i suppose.

Comment: in your on click lv.setAdapter(your adapter);

Comment: great that solved the setadapter. still something wrong with simplecursoradapter.

Comment: says constructor for simplecursoradapter undefined

Comment: MyCustomAdapter c=new MyCustomAdapter(); what does this do? if you have a custom adapter you can set that to listview

Comment: i use that to retrieve the tag set on the button with getTag() and pass the parameter to retrieve childId and use that value to getRecord() function.

Comment: set customadapter to list view meaning?

Comment: pls put your updated code. If you have custom adapter. lv.setAdapter(CustomAdapter). in your custom adapter you inlfate custom layout for each row in listview